# Django: Query which excludes all children if the parent is included in the query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

```
class Person(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    is_child = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
```

I am trying to form a query which excludes all children if their parent is present. Children, represent a 30% of the model's entries -for the time being- in my PostgreSQL.

My approach would be to use a [nested query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in). However, I am not sure that it would be the most efficient solution.

I would appreciate your help.

**Update**

The python solution I came up with is the following:

```
a = Person.objects.filter(...)
ids = [i.id for i in a]
result = [x for x in a if any((not x.is_child, x.parent_id not in ids))]
```

Comment: In terms of performance, I don't see why you wouldn't just perform the original query and exclude the children in python code from the result. But measuring query times is probably the best way to tell. Your approach of using a nested query should work fine in PostgreSQL by the way.

Comment: @dirkgroten Indeed, this is a good point, I will test it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
qs0 = Person.objects.filter(...)
qs = qs0.exclude(is_child=True, parent__in=qs0)
```